# How to sort scraped items?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have working scraper here but im struggling with sorting the data.

Here is the scraper code:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function (error, response,
    html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var list_items = "";
        var arr = [];
        var arr2 = [];
        var j = 1;
        $('div.match_line.score_row.other_match.e_true').each(function (i, element) {
            var a = $(this).attr('data-home-team');
            arr.push(a + " Row Number " + j);
            j = j + 2;
            //list_items += "<li>" + a + "</li>";
            //console.log(arr.length);
        });
        var j = 2;
        $('div.match_line.score_row.other_match.o_true').each(function (i, element) {
            var b = $(this).attr('data-home-team');
            arr.push(b + " Row Number " + j);
            j = j + 2;
            //list_items += "<li>" + b + "</li>";
            //console.log(arr.length);
        });
        var arrayLength = arr.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            list_items += "<li>" + arr[i] + "</li>";
        }
        var html = "<ul>" + list_items + "</ul>"
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        res.end(html);
        console.log(arr.length);
    }
});
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running at http://178.62.253.206:8080/');
```

**So to the problem, Sorting these elements.**

- Element 'div.match_line.score_row.other_match.e_true' are in placed every nth 
  Odd Row Number in the source page.
- And element 'div.match_line.score_row.other_match.o_true' are in placed every nth Even Row Number in the source page.

**The way It gets sorted now**

- My array(arr) first pushes all rows of data into the array from the first 
  element (odd row number)
- Then array(arr) pushes all rows of data from the 2nd element into the same 
  array. (even row number)

So basically items in my array is sorted like this 1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8 (shortened)

**How can I sort this so I can output this in correct order ?**

Any suggestion for a solution would be much appreciated

Frederik

Comment: It would be useful to show an example of the data you want to sort

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , I will update code in #post 1 , Please see my server page , I added to the items "Row Number + number" to show where the item was meant to be inserted

Comment: If you're asking how to sort some data then don't post code of how you're going to insert it, as that's not relevant.  Post the data you want sorted and explain how you want the sort to work.

Comment: To be honest I posted my entire code as i'm not exactly sure if I store it the best way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `arr.sort` method below.

```js
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function(error, response,
    html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var list_items = "";
      var arr = [];
      var arr2 = [];
      var j = 1;
      $('div.match_line.score_row.other_match.e_true').each(function(i, element) {
        var a = $(this).attr('data-home-team');
        arr.push({
          html: a,
          j: j
        });
        j = j + 2;
        //list_items += "<li>" + a + "</li>";
        //console.log(arr.length);
      });
      var j = 2;
      $('div.match_line.score_row.other_match.o_true').each(function(i, element) {
        var b = $(this).attr('data-home-team');
        arr.push({
          html: b,
          j: j
        });
        j = j + 2;
        //list_items += "<li>" + b + "</li>";
        //console.log(arr.length);
      });

      arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.j - b.j
      })

      var arrayLength = arr.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        list_items += "<li>" + arr[i].html + "</li>";
      }
      var html = "<ul>" + list_items + "</ul>"
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      });
      res.end(html);
      console.log(arr.length);
    }
  });
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running at http://178.62.253.206:8080/');
```

Comment: It did indeed work , and I think I'm quite happy with this solution , Will this also work for a multidimensional array ?

Comment: Ouch It did not work after I removed the " Row Number " + j); That was only meant to be there in the testing stage...

Comment: It depends on `" Row Number " + j`. If you need to do it right, put your rows in an object with a property of `j` and sort them with it.

Comment: Could I make arr [] as a multidimensional array perhaps ? and just store j as "Entry" , then sort it based on J . Im really lost here ?

Comment: if im gonna use your solution I would need to create another loop to remove "extra text" . I don't think that is the best , but of course its better then what I can come up with..

Comment: Check the answer now, I did what I was trying to explain! Also why do you need a multidimensional array?

Comment: Id figured it would be easier to handle the data that way,  This script is just in the starting stage, The element im scraping attribute from also have around 8 more selection I would like to scrape

Comment: Your latest solution was exactly what I wanted thanks a lot